# Codeigniter get database records when number of selected field is unknown

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form field, with around 40 checkboxes. When users ticks checkboxes, depending upon the checked checkbox, the fields from database is selected. So, they can check all or any of them to show what fields in the report. I have made successful sql query and it executes well. All i m having problem is looping through the record set and populating the html table because I m unknown what columns they selected to show. I m trying to sorting out the issue, but nothing is coming in my head right now. Any help will be highly appreciated. I just need an idea! I m using the query method of the codeigniter-

```
$query=$this->db->query($sql);
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, how are the chckboxes related to the record in the database ? By name ?

Comment: well check box contains values like `p.tr-p-name`, which means `p.p_name` in the sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looping through the dataset like they do in the documentation [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide//database/results.html), why don't you just get the result_array() then retrieve the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) while you're looping through each row?

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox values match up by name, then you should be able to use PHP's `implode()` function to put all the fields into a comma seperated list:

```
implode(',', $checkboxes); // returns string like 'field1,field2,field3,field4'
```

You could assign this to a variable and put it into your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: i have already put it into select statement, infact i have already made sql query working, All i m having problem is iterating through a loop of recordset to populate html table, I don't know what user selected and what records are returned by the query, further don't know which field to show in which `<td></td>` of the table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue, **the only place you know what the user want** is in the "`checkboxes`" page where you can understand the request based on the actual check boxes pressed.
So you will have to **save this information** (*in session variables, DB, CI controller or few other options*)

Once you saved the information, you can use it to build your "results page"